# How to do asynchronous calls in vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, axios

I managed to use axios by putting this link in my html:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
```

What I am trying to do is call axios twice, once to call my http request to send in a JSON Object, and another to send in a file along with the JSON object. What I want to do is to make it so that it is required for both to be sent, meaning that the user cannot just send the JSON object by itself or the file by itself. However, my code does not check for that for some reason. I believe it is due to async not being present, But idk how to add that when I am using vanilla js. Here is my code:

```
 axios.post('/account/signup', userObj).then((profile)=>{
        //data returns current user info, including if they are verified or not
        return axios.post('/account/signup/veteranFile-upload', formData)
    }).then(()=>{
        //window.location.replace('/')
        console.log('Hello?')
    }).catch( function (error){
        showAppropriateTextSignUp(error.response.data, signupErr)
    })
```

For some extra info, my model requires the file and the JSON data being sent.

Comment: `make it so that it is required for both to be sent, meaning that the user cannot just send the JSON object` this is impossible to enforce due to the nature of the web. You will always have to account for the possibility that only one of the requests fire. Even the second one could fire while the first one doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

your second `then` is in the wrong place. also is formData defined?

```
axios.post('/account/signup', userObj).then((profile)=>{
    //data returns current user info, including if they are verified or not
    return axios.post('/account/signup/veteranFile-upload', formData).then(()=>{
        //window.location.replace('/')
        console.log('Hello?')
    }).catch( function (error){        
        showAppropriateTextSignUp(error.response.data, signupErr)
   });
});
```

a much cleaner way: use async await:

```
const api = async() => {
  try{
    const profile = await axios.post('/account/signup', userObj);
    const whatever = axios.post('/account/signup/veteranFile-upload', formData);
    console.log(whatever)
  } catch (e) {
    showAppropriateTextSignUp(error.response.data, signupErr)
  }
}
```

Comment: I actually put the .then inside initially, but it did not work so i started experimenting and got the current code above. Also, I tried your method and it does not seem to work for me :(

Answer (score 0):

you might need to chain the axios call instead of returning. That is

```
    axios.post('/account/signup', userObj)
          .then((profile)=>{
            //current user info, including if they are verified or not
            axios.post('/account/signup/veteranFile-upload', formData).then(resp=>{
                     //do something with the response
                    //window.location.replace('/')
           }).catch(err=>{
                   console.log(err)
           })
            console.log('Hello?')
        }).catch( function (error){
            showAppropriateTextSignUp(error.response.data, signupErr)
        })
```